# Include files in bundle across projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have a Visual Studio solution witch contains 2 projects (websites):

```
Solution
  - Project A
      - App_Start
         - BundleConfig.cs
      - Scripts

  - Project B
      - App_Start
      - Scripts
         - my_file.js
```

Is there a way to include files from `Project B` at `Project A`, using bundles?:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(
         new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/my_bundle")
              // This obviously doesn't work
              .Include("~/../Scripts/my_file.js")

              // Neither does this
              .Include("../../../Scripts/my_file.js")
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the project B files comeng from the project A by linking them instead of copy it, and then add to your bundle. Rember that you can add files to your prject as reference-only.